# get every page under a website

Tags: java, php

I need a program to get all the web pages under a website. The website is Chinese, I want to get all those English words out. Then I can extract all the information I need. Any ideas for this? Is there any software for this purpose?

If NO, I would like to write one. Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: http://www.spidersoft.com/ if no wget available

Answer (score 10):

Use eg `wget -r http://site.to.copy.com` to recursively retrieve all the web pages to your local machine (hope it's not too big...), then you can search or do whatever with the files afterwards.

Comment: What I was going to suggest. Why bother building yet another mousetrap?

Comment: You may want to consider using "--convert-links" flag also so that you can browse locally...

Comment: Depending on how many pages you're intending to download, you might also make sure to specify the --limit-rate option to avoid overloading the server.

Answer (score 3):

Your pretty much describing a web crawler (something that takes a page, looks for all the links, follows them etc). There are crawler implementations already out there, tool that act like crawlers (such as wget), and questions relating to them here on Stack Overflow. For example...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102631/how-to-write-a-crawler

Once you have something that can visit each page you then need code that'll parse the page and look for the text you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

`wget` ([manpage here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)) can also serve well as a crawler, look at its `--recursive` option.

Answer (score 1):

Not a PHP solution, but you can use the [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) text-only Web browser with the `-crawl` and `-dump` options to visit all the pages on a site and dump them as text files. You can then use a script to extract the information you want from them.